# Chained hash-table declaration

Tags: c, hashtable, chained

In Master Algorithm with C, the author has declared the structure of a chained hash table like below:

```
typedef struct CHTbl_ {

int                buckets;

int                (*h)(const void *key);
int                (*match)(const void *key1, const void *key2);
void               (*destroy)(void *data);

int                size;
List               *table;

} CHTbl;
```

But I thought the last one should be `List               *table[buckets];`
as the author has used something like `&htbl->table[bucket]`. Am I right? Why the author's definition could correctly pass the test?why is it right? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `table` is a `List` pointer, and is being used to represent an array of `List`s. It is probably being initialized like this:

```
htbl->table = malloc(sizeof(List) * htbl->buckets);
```